# Does javascript get the value once?

Tags: php, jquery, session-variables

I am using codeigniter and i am combining jquery.
my problem is that i have a menu with different anchor tags.
when the anchor tag is clicked, the iframe src is changed,
but when i click the menu item i would like to check session if he is logged in so that i can redirect my page to logout.

the var logged servers as the sentinel value for the check. unfortunately, when i open logout in a new tag leaving the master layout as it is then click other menu item, the logged is still having a value of 1 which means true and logged_in. I'd like to ask for help to this approach.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('a').click(function(event) {

            var logged = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('logged_in'); ?>";
            alert(logged);

            if(logged == 1)
                $("#frame").attr("src", $(this).attr("id"));    
            else
                window.location.replace("https://www.facebook.com");
        });
```

Comment: what is the result of this: <?php echo $this->session->userdata('logged_in'); ?>

Comment: If you look at the generated page (what the browser sees after PHP has created the page) using View/Source in your browser, your answer will be a lot clearer and you'll now how to investigate this kind of question yourself next time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, php is hypertext pre-processor which means server processes data before js become active on your page. So, once "logged" is set to true, it will remain until you reload the page.

You need to use ajax to make your script working. Invoke an ajax function call here:

```
     var logged = get_session_via_ajax_function();
     alert(logged);
     get_session_via_ajax_function(){....your ajax code here...}
```

"get_session_via_ajax_function()" is not a real function, just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('a').click(function(event) {

           var logged =0;    
           $.ajax({
                  type: "post",
                  url: baseurl+"get_seesion_details",
                  async:false,
                  success: function(data, status){
                           logged = data;
                  } 
           });

           if(logged == 1)
               $("#frame").attr("src", $(this).attr("id"));    
           else
               window.location.replace("https://www.facebook.com");
      });
});
```

in codeigniter

```
function get_seesion_detail(){

    $is_logged  = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    echo $is_logged;

}
```